# How to install Adobe Air for macOS Sierra w/o administrator access

Tags: administrator, macos-sierra, adobe-air

I am trying to install Adobe Air on my MacBook using macOS Sierra version 10.12.4. I can get as far as downloading the AdobeAIR.dmg file, opening the .dmg file, opening the Adobe Air Installer, and accepting the Installer Setup terms, but when I select “I Agree”, it pop-up appears saying “Adobe AIR Installer wants to make changes. Enter an administrator’s name and password to allow this,” and asks for the administrator username and password. I do not know either, I simply would like a way to bypass this step. I have searched for answers, but all the solutions I’ve found are for Windows, not macOS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to happen.

If you are on a managed account & don't know any admin credentials, you're not going to do it. That's what security is all about.

The ***only*** way to do it would be to completely wipe the machine & start over... but your admin might just notice that ;)